# Firebase query between two latitudes

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having trouble receiving data from my database where the latitude of a post is within +/- 0.1 of the user's current latitude.

My Firebase tree is as follows:

```
{
"person" : {
  "ss" : {
    "email" : "contact@surrogatesystems.com",
    "username" : "Surrogate Systems"
  },
  "CZ6Ujxsm0SXybtcLBthXOpG3YgU2" : {
    "email" : "ljahnke9@gmail.com",
    "username" : "Logan Jahnke"
  }
},
"prayers" : {
  "p0" : {
    "contents" : "For understanding of Firebase as we build the Surge: Prayer Sharing application.",
    "likes" : 100,
    "personid" : "ss",
    "posted" : "2016-06-21 20:15:00",
    "latitude" : 33.9441737581188,
    "longitude" : -83.3843067012304
  },
  "p1" : {
    "contents" : "This is a test prayer.",
    "likes" : 0,
    "personid" : "CZ6Ujxsm0SXybtcLBthXOpG3YgU2",
    "posted" : "2016-06-21 20:00:00",
    "latitude" : 33.9441737581188,
    "longitude" : -83.3843067012304
  },
  "p2" : {
    "contents" : "My prayer request is that every child in Los Andes, Panama know the love of Jesus Christ. I also pray for their families and their friends. I pray that their education runs smoothly and that they learn the English they desire to know. I pray that we made an impact on them.",
    "likes" : 0,
    "personid" : "CZ6Ujxsm0SXybtcLBthXOpG3YgU2",
    "posted" : "2016-06-21 20:00:00",
    "latitude" : 35.3341737581184,
    "longitude" : -81.3843067012304
}
```

}
}

The latitude and longitude are of type `Double`. My current query is:

```
let lat = // user's latitude by using CLLocation -> ~33.9
let query = ref.child("prayers").queryStartingAtValue(lat - 0.1, childKey: "latitude").queryEndingAtValue(lat + 0.1, childKey: "latitude").queryLimitedToFirst(50)
// This should theoretically return a list of size 2
```

This returns an NSNull upon calling for the snapshot even though there are entires in my system that fit the criteria.

What is wrong with my call, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you show some actual JSON data from your database that you'd expect to match this query? You can easily get that from your Firebase Database console by clicking the export button. YHaving the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I see the same behavior. I get the expected results by inserting a call to queryOrderedByChild:

```
    let query = ref.child("prayers")
                .queryOrderedByChild("latitude")
                .queryStartingAtValue(lat - 0.1)
                .queryEndingAtValue(lat + 0.1)
                .queryLimitedToFirst(50)
                .observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
                    print(snapshot)
                })
```

Comment: What does the `observeEventType` look like for you? Mine is: `query.observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in` and my `snapshot` is `null`

Comment: added it to the answer

Comment: That seemed to work, however, the `snapshot` was only one prayer broken up into 6 keys (the keys of the prayer). I need the `snapshot` to be `[Prayer : Key]` rather than `[Key : Value]`.